# workout in weekdays & eating protein in weekend?

Tags: muscle, protein

I workout on **Monday - thursday** & dont take required amount of protein to build muscles due to some reasons....

i can able to take enough protein  from **friday to sunday**.... so if i need **150g  protein per day to gain muscle, if i take **50 g** protein per day from **monday to thursday** & if i take **150 g** protein per day from **friday to sunday** , will that helpfull to build muscles ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

50g of protein per day is extremely low, and would be less than the recommended dietary allowance for a sedentary person weighting 62.5kg. If you weigh more than 62.5kg or you perform exercise, then you need more protein than that.

I'm not aware of any studies specifically looking at delays between exercise and protein ingestion on the scale of days, but it has been shown that even delaying protein intake by 2 hours is enough to make the exercise wasted[1]. Furthermore, as recovery from exercise is widely held to have a duration of around 48 hours, it seems highly unlikely that you would benefit from exercising Monday to Thursday while consuming insufficient protein and then only beginning to eat sufficient protein on Friday, as at absolute best, you'd be starting to consume sufficient protein half way through your recovery from Thursday's exercise.

[1] https://physoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1469-7793.2001.00301.x

Answer (score 2):

No, 50 grams certainly isn’t enough to build muscle, and it may not even be enough to maintain good health, not unless you are especially small (minimum is 0.8 grams per kg of body weight). Doing more protein for three days isn’t going to offset the malnourishment enough to start building muscle.

Bottom line, you need more protein. I’m not sure what reasons are preventing you from having more throughout the week, but protein is easily accessible. There are cheap options (tuna, eggs, bulk quantities of whey), vegan options (soy), and options for pretty much anything really.